# How to know which driver is right for SM Bus Controller?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, device-manager

I'm having a problem with the SM Bus controller. it appears with an explanation mark in Device manager. I would install the driver manually but i'm not sure which is the right one. I don't know what device is that actually. How can i know? It seems like it's a known problem but i didn't find a good answer for my question. 
I'm using Windows 8.1 64-bit:

Gigabyte Z97-d3h MoBo.

Intel CPU 4790k.

Kingston HyperX 16GB RAM.

MSI gtx970 4G GPU.

Kingston 3TB HDD.

Samsung Evo 250GB SSD.

EVGA 650W Gold PSU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install latest Intel Chipset Software Installation Utility, latest Intel Management Engine Interface and latest Intel Rapid Storage Technology.

Comment: Intel Chipset Software Installation Utility was enough. Thanks.

Comment: You should install all of it

Comment: Why should i install the rest? How are they important?

Comment: Intel Management Engine Interface is important for managing your components, overclocking and Intel Rapid Storage Technology is important for optimal performance of SSD and RAID.